# Disable specified USB port when PC is in sleep - Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, sleep

I recently got a [RGB Light Strip](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07XQ57P6K/ref=ox_sc_act_title_3?smid=AYK2KR1XJXN0U&psc=1) which plugs into a USB port on my PC.
So I was wondering if there is a way that I can disable the USB port (which the strip is plugged into) whilst the PC is in sleep mode (which will save the life of the strip for the occasions I forget to turn off my strip)

I am aware of how to disable power to USB whilst it is shutdown, but I need to know if I can do a similar thing for a single USB whilst sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal method to turn USB power off. USB specifications allows for both types of ports: ports with "ganged" uncontrolled power (when VBUS comes from PC's +5V standby rail), and ports with individual power control. The type of ports usually are not communicated to end PC user, so you never know what kind of port control is inside your particular PC. Therefore some PC can turn power off when in "soft shutdown", some PC cannot turn VBUS off if they are connected to AC and not in "mechanical OFF".

If your PC does have individual port power control in hardware (has some specialized IC with "high-side power switch" per port or per a pair o stacked USB ports), there can be a way to turn the VBUS off on individual ports, in theory. But this function is not in the standard-defined root hub behavior, and thus it is not implemented in general USB stack software. Per USB idea, it is a function of USB device to enter SUSPEND mode when the bus turns off its data activity, and enter low-power mode internally. Therefore the USB software deems disabling the port power unnecessary.

You probably can write so-called "filter driver" for xHCI controller using Windows DDK, but it would require certain software skills and deep familiarity with Windows OS. But again, it will work only on handful of (usually high-end business-class) PCs.